# SailsJs - problems with lifting (orm hook failed to load)

Tags: orm, sails.js, hook

I am having problems with running my app under windows. Normally, I am developing on Macbook but temporarly I had to switch. The thing is, that the app was already working on windows without problems. Here is an error message:

> error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
>       verbose: Lowering sails...
>       verbose: Sent kill signal to child process (8684)...
>       verbose: Shutting down HTTP server...
>       verbose: HTTP server shut down successfully.
>       error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
>           at validateModelDef (C:\projects\elearning-builder\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib
>       \validate-model-def.js:109:84)
>           at C:\projects\elearning-builder\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\initialize.js:218
>       :36
>           at arrayEach (C:\projects\elearning-builder\node_modules\sails\node_modules\lodash\index.js:1289:13)
>           at Function. (C:\projects\elearning-builder\node_modules\sails\node_modules\lodash\index.j
>       s:3345:13)
>           at Array.async.auto._normalizeModelDefs (C:\projects\elearning-builder\node_modules\sails\node_module
>       s\sails-hook-orm\lib\initialize.js:216:11)
>           at listener (C:\projects\elearning-builder\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\node_module
>       s\async\lib\async.js:605:42)
>           at C:\projects\elearning-builder\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\node_modules\async\li
>       b\async.js:544:17
>           at _arrayEach (C:\projects\elearning-builder\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\node_modu
>       les\async\lib\async.js:85:13)
>           at Immediate.taskComplete (C:\projects\elearning-builder\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-o
>       rm\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:543:13)
>           at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
>       PS C:\projects\elearning-builder>

I tried to check it out, what exactly is happening in `\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-orm\lib\validate-model-def.js:109:84`
    so I added simple console.log temporarly:

```
  console.log("error in line below", hook);
  var normalizedDatastoreConfig = hook.datastores[normalizedModelDef.connection[0]].config;
```

And as a result I see:

```
error in line below Hook {
  load: [Function: wrapper],
  defaults:
   { globals: { adapters: true, models: true },
     orm: { skipProductionWarnings: false, moduleDefinitions: [Object] },
     models: { connection: 'localDiskDb' },
     connections: { localDiskDb: [Object] } },
  configure: [Function: wrapper],
  loadModules: [Function: wrapper],
  initialize: [Function: wrapper],
  config: { envs: [] },
  middleware: {},
  routes: { before: {}, after: {} },
  reload: [Function: wrapper],
  teardown: [Function: wrapper],
  identity: 'orm',
  configKey: 'orm',
  models:
   { /* models here, I removed this as it was too long /*},
  adapters: {},
  datastores: {} }
```

So, the `normalizedModelDef.connection[0]` has value `development`. But hook.datastores is empty? That is why there is no `config` property.

But the thing is, I do have connections in my config/connections.js

Like here:

```
development: {
        module    : 'sails-mysql',
        host      : 'localhost',
        port      : 3306,
        user      : 'ebuilder',
        password  : 'ebuilder',
        database  : 'ebuilder'
    },
    production: {
        /* details hidden ;) */
    },
    testing: {
        /* details hidden ;) */
    }
```

Any suggestions/tips highly appreciated.

Comment: Check all your models definitions

Comment: No problems there. Everything seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

You have some connections defined, but do you have the default connection defined that might be specified in config/models.js? If for example you have:

```
    module.exports.models = {
      connection: 'mysql',
      ...
```

then 'mysql' needs to be defined in your connections.js

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your config/connections.js

```
development: {
        module    : 'sails-mysql',
        host      : 'localhost',
        port      : 3306,
        user      : 'ebuilder',
        password  : 'ebuilder',
        database  : 'ebuilder'
    },
```

You have given `module : 'sails-mysql` which is not correct. It should be `adapter:'sails-mysql'`

```
development: {
        adapter   : 'sails-mysql',
        host      : 'localhost',
        port      : 3306,
        user      : 'ebuilder',
        password  : 'ebuilder',
        database  : 'ebuilder'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

check your controller or models contains any error code. like any symbol. i had face same problem while my controller contain any character before or after api started